# What is the probability that the receiver catches the ball?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, uniform-distribution

A quarterback needs to throw the ball quickly,
and in his haste, the location it lands is Uniformly distributed within a $30×120$
sq. ft. area in the endzone. The receiver can only catch the ball the ball lands
within $7$ feet of him, i.e., within a circle of radius $7$ feet, completely contained
in the endzone. What is the probability that the receiver catches the ball?
(Assume that the receiver is positioned so that a circle of $7$ feet around him is
completely contained within the endzone.)

So the joint pdf for the rectangular endzone region is clearly $f(x,y) = 1/3600$ since it's just the area of the endzone region ($30 \cdot 120$), But I'm a little confused on where to go from here since we want to calculate the probability associated with the part of the endzone region that represents the receiver whose joint pdf is $1/(49\pi)$ as the area of the circle is $\pi r^2 = \pi7^2 = 49\pi$

I want to make sure that my logic is right.

Method 1: Using area.
If the area of the rectangular region is $3600$ and the area of the circular region within the rectangular region is $49\pi$ then using proportionality, the probability is $\cfrac{49\pi}{3600}$

Method 2: Polar coordinates.

$P$(Reciever catching) $= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^7 \cfrac{r}{3600} drd\theta = \cfrac{49\pi}{3600}$ My logic is if $f(x,y) = 1/3600$ represents the rectangular region, then using the polar coordinates from $0 \leq r \leq 7$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ for the rectangular joint pdf would represent the region of the circle within the rectangle giving us the probability.

Are both methods fine? Is one wrong and the other right? Is my answer way off? Please let me know! Thank You!

Comment: yes, there was a similar problem yesterday about swatting a fly. both answers are correct.

Comment: Ok thank you! by the way, the area proportionality works out because both regions have the same constant density ($1/3600$) (as the circle is within the rectangle $1/49\pi$ would be if it wasn't part of the rectangle) so the only thing that matters is the area correct? Just want to make sure I understand this so that I'm not doing this without knowing.